# How to fit a linear model including the expectation and a transformation

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I have to fit a linear model for

```
E(ᴪ(Y)) = β0+ β1X1+ β2X2+ β3X3
```

where ᴪ is a modified Box-Cox transformation  given by:

[image]

and β0,1,2,3 are parameters.
My data frame is a shown as below which I read into **R** as

```
data<-read.table("surveydata.txt", header=TRUE)
```

[image]

I'm fairly new to **R** and I haven't been able to fit the model. I know how to fit a model using using lm, but wasn't sure how I'll fit it while including the transformation and the expectation.

So far I've tried:

```
>lm(mean(boxcox(Y))~X1+X2+X3,data)
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for suggestions on how people can reproduce your problem. A good first step would be including the dataset with `dput()`, rather than as an image.

Comment: First thing to try: leave out the `mean` in the `lm`

Comment: Why don't you just run `boxcox(Y ~ X1 + X1 + X3, data, plotit = F)` ?

Comment: I too out the mean, got the same error back

Comment: David, I did that and it prints the lambda vs log likelihood. How do i get from this to a fitted model?

Comment: You obviosuly didn't do that with `plotit = F` like i showed. If you do that that way, you"ll get your fitted model. Run `boxcox(Y ~ X1 + X1 + X3, data, plotit = F)$y`

Comment: I'll make an answer from it so it will be answered

Answer (score 1):

```
boxcox(Y ~ X1 + X1 + X3, data, plotit = F)$y
```

Comment: If this the answer you were looking for, please select it as one, thanks